# LU decomposition for symmetric tridiagonal matrix with partial pivoting in O(n)

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition

I am looking to implement an algorithm for LU decomposition with partial pivoting for tridiagonal symmetric matrix, which would only require O(n) space and O(n) operations.
I have LU decomposition algorithm where you input the matrix as three vectors which represent the non-zero elements in the matrix (all three diagonals), but I am stuck at the idea of how to implement a version of this algorithm which wouldn't require storing the L and U as full matrices. The problem I have is that as soon as you start pivoting rows, the L and U aren't bi diagonal anymore.
Any tips or documentation on this topic will be very much appreciated